# The targetSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest file

Tags: android

La versión de targetSdk no debe declararse en el archivo de manifiesto de Android. Puede mover la versión del manifiesto al defaultConfig en el archivo build.gradle.

me da este error al hacerle cambio de api a la 26, en el manifiesto ya no esta.

asi esta mi código.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx.xxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

esto lo tengo en el archivo build.gradle, y en el manifiesto no tengo nada de eso, pero aun así me sigue dando el error.

Comment: `File` -> `Invalidate caches / restart`

Comment: Revisa que el archivo AndroidManifest.xml que editas no sea el que se encuentra dentro del directorio /build , esto puede ser una causa del problema, limpia y construye nuevamente tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Asegura eliminar la declaración de [android:targetSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#target) (incluso `android:minSdkVersion` y  `android:maxSdkVersion`) dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="?"
          android:targetSdkVersion="?"
          android:maxSdkVersion="?" />
```

No es necesario definir estos valores puesto que este valor lo estas declarando dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` y esta configuración sobrescribe a la del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx.xxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

- Asegura que el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`que editas no sea el que se encuentre dentro del directorio `/build`

Si tu proyecto indica que aún tienes esta configuración puedes limpiar el proyecto y volver a construirlo,

`Clean` > `Build Project`